# Non linear regression with nls2 package

Tags: r

I work on agglomeration effect and i want to run a non linear regression with package nls2.

I am trying to run this model with R

```
dens=runif(100)
surf=rnorm(100, 10, 2)  
zone=seq(1,100,1)  
donnees<-data.frame(dens,surf,zone)   
attach(donnees) 
donnees$salaire<-rnorm(100, 1000,3)    
mp<-rep(0,100)    
MP<-rep(0,100)
MPfonc<-function(alpha){    
for (i in 1:100){    
   for (j in 1:100){    
     if(j!=i){    
    mp[j]<- dens[j]/(surf[i]-surf[j])^alpha
     }
  }    
  MP[i]<-sum(mp)    
}    
  return(MP)    
}

fo <- salaire ~ const+ gamma1*dens+gamma2*surf+gamma3*MPfonc(alpha)

gstart <- data.frame(const = c(-100, 100), gamma1 = c(-10, 10),
       gamma2 = c(-10, 10),gamma3 = c(-10, 10), alpha=c(-10, 10))
fm <- nls2(fo, start = gstart,  alg = "plinear-random")
```

It does not run and I think it is a problem of alpha.
Can `nls2` function accept a function `(MP(alpha))` as an input?

Here is the specification of my model:

[image: nonlinear regression equations]

Answer (score 3):

The problems are:

- `set.seed` should be set to make the code reproducible
- `salaire` is not defined -- it is defined in the data frame `donnees` but `donnees` is never used after that.
- the elements summed in the `sum` call in `MPfonc` include NaN or NA elements so the sum becomes similarly undefined
- For `plinear` algorithms the RHS of the formula must evaluate to a matrix of coefficients of the linear parameters.
- For the `plinear` algorithms provide starting values only for the non-linear parameters (i.e. only for `alpha`).
- the nls2 package is never loaded.  A `library` statement is needed.
- code posted to SO should be indented 4 spaces to cause it to format properly (this was addressed in an edit to the question)
- the mathematical formulas in the question are not clear in how they relate to the problem and are missing significant elements, e.g. `alpha`.  This needs to be cleaned up.   We have assumed that `MPfonc` gives the desired result and just simplified it.

The following corrects all the points and adds some minor improvements.

```
library(nls2)

set.seed(123) # for reproducibility

dens <- runif(100)
surf <- rnorm(100, 10, 2)
zone <- seq(1, 100, 1)
salaire <- rnorm(100, 1000, 3)

MPfonc <- function(alpha) {
  sapply(1:100, function(i) sum( (dens / (surf[i] - surf) ^ alpha)[-i], na.rm = TRUE ))
}

fo <- salaire ~ cbind(1, dens, surf, MPfonc(alpha))
gstart <- data.frame(alpha = c(-10, 10))

fm <- nls2(fo, start = gstart, alg = "plinear-random")
```

giving:

```
> fm
Nonlinear regression model
  model: salaire ~ cbind(1, dens, surf, MPfonc(alpha))
   data: parent.frame()
     alpha      .lin1  .lin.dens  .lin.surf      .lin4 
   0.90477 1001.20905   -0.50642   -0.12269    0.00681 
 residual sum-of-squares: 757.6

Number of iterations to convergence: 50 
Achieved convergence tolerance: NA
```

**Note:** Now that we have the starting value we can use it with `nls` like this:

```
nls(fo, start = coef(fm)["alpha"], alg = "plinear")
```

**Update:**  Some code improvements, corrections and clarifications.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But why the model does not converged : Achieved convergence tolerance: NA. It's normal?

Comment: It's the first time i ask a question on this website because i had found every thing i searched on without asking question. Normally, all mathematical should be present. But i have focused only in MPfonc because others are linear form. I have also another question, witch algorithm should fit the best my model? Does starting values of alpha impact on his estimation ?

Comment: Convergence has no meaning here -- that is why it is NA.  The purpose of `nls2` is to find starting values.  With the specified `alg=` it is just evaluating the model at 50 random points and then returning the best one found.  You can then use the resulting coefs as starting values in `nls`.

Comment: If i take for an interval of alpha 0-1, i obtain 0.82825659 (estimation of alpha). So, should i take a reasonable starting values of alpha? When using nls, will i also take as algorithm pllinear?

Comment: Have added Note near end of answer.